# What's the cost of unpacking collections?

Tags: python, collections

I'm measuring the running time of different functions, which take different number of arguments. Instead of writing measuring code for each function separately, I wanted to consolidate everything into one function. Since every function to be measured takes different number of arguments, I thought unpacking would be helpful.

Here's the code:

```
import resource 

def resource_runtime_unpack(f, repeats, args):
    """
    Measures running time of a function using the resource module.
    Index 0 is user time, index 1 is the system time.
    Unpacks a list of arguments into the function.
    """
    start = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
    for i in xrange(repeats): 
        f(*args)
    end   = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
    return (end.ru_utime - start.ru_utime, 
            end.ru_stime - start.ru_stime)
```

Every iteration the arguments are being unpacked, so it will be reflected in the results, which made me wonder: what's the cost of unpacking?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is the cost constant, then? No matter the size of the collection that is being unpacked?

Comment: Python uses the [`CALL_FUNCTION_VAR` opcode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION_VAR) for the call, so from the evaluation loop the cost is constant. The C code for invoking the function then creates a tuple from the sequence and updates the argument sequence from that. That has a cost proportional to the argument list but that's entirely in C code. Compared to everything else your code does that cost is going to drop into nothingness.

Comment: Scratch that, the cost is larger than I thought, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could measure this yourself, using the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def variable_args_factory(n):
...     template = 'def noop({}): pass'
...     args = ', '.join(['arg{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(n)])
...     namespace = {}
...     exec(template.format(args), namespace)
...     return namespace['noop']
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('noop()', 'from __main__ import variable_args_factory; noop = variable_args_factory(0)')
0.08463001251220703
>>> timeit.timeit('noop(*args)', 'from __main__ import variable_args_factory; noop = variable_args_factory(0); args = []')
0.11967301368713379
>>> timeit.timeit('noop(*args)', 'from __main__ import variable_args_factory; noop = variable_args_factory(10); args = [None] * 10')
0.22447800636291504
>>> timeit.timeit('noop(*args)', 'from __main__ import variable_args_factory; noop = variable_args_factory(100); args = [None] * 100')
1.5113048553466797
>>> timeit.timeit('noop(*args)', 'from __main__ import variable_args_factory; noop = variable_args_factory(1000); args = [None] * 1000')
12.78959608078003
```

So yes, there is a cost involved with unpacking arguments that increases as the number of arguments increases. The above timings are per 1 million invocations, so a list with 10 arguments takes about twice the time to unpack as a list with 0 arguments.

That overhead is small however; if `noop()` did actual work instead of just be an empty function, the cost of the unpacking would be a small fraction of the overall function time.

Comment: I don’t think the large overhead is necessarily from the unpacking but more from the packing again from your variable `*args` of your `noop` function. Compare your time with this: `timeit.timeit('noop({})'.format(', '.join(itertools.repeat('None', 100))), 'from __main__ import noop')`.

Comment: @poke: perhaps the timings should be re-run with functions that take that many arguments. The arguments being packed back into the `*args` parameter for the `noop()` function could be a factor, indeed.

Comment: @poke: I eliminated the variable argument count in the `noop()` function, timings did not shift much.